# OpenWRT router as a bridge to a corporate network

Tags: networking, router, bridge, openwrt, gateway

I have an OpenWRT router (192.168.101.160) connected to an office network behind an HTTP-proxy (192.168.101.127:3128) and I need to make it share the connection to the Internet over Wi-fi. But it must not be just a bridge that would make the Wi-Fi clients a part of the 192.168.101.* subnet (the number of free IP addresses is limited). The router must allot IP addresses in the range of 192.168.10.1-255 over Wi-Fi and transparently route all the internet traffic through the corporate HTTP-proxy, so the Wi-Fi users don't need to change any proxy settings on their devices. [Please consider the scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZUh2.jpg). How do I do that? (And yes of course I have the permission from the sysadmin.)

Comment: I don't understand what problem you're facing. The proxy has an independent address that clients able to use. Clients will need some form of proxy configuration. So you'd just need to setup the router as a regular router?

Comment: The problem is, I need WiFi clients to be in a different network (192.168.10.*) and their HTTP(S) traffic to be transparently forwarded to the proxy in the office network (192.168.101.127).

Comment: You're not supposed to change the proxy configuration of said clients. Do they have a proxy configuration? If so why would it not work?

Comment: Wi-Fi clients don't and are not supposed to have any idea of proxy configuration. I need their traffic to be forwarded transparently to the corporate proxy. I created 2 interfaces. LAN is connected to the corporate network (192.168.101.160) and WiFi (192.168.10.1). Wi-Fi clients who don't belong to the corporate network get addresses in the range of (192.168.10.2-255) over the DHCP server running on the router. But they can't access any resources in the 192.168.101.* subnet. The question is, how to share the internet with them transparently for them.